# Type of object question

Tags: c#, interface, types

In C#, i have an interface, and there are some class will implement this interface.
i have a generic utility class, which i want to limit so that the utility class can only be declared using types implementing that interface, as show below, how can i do it??

```
public interface IMyInterface 
{}

public class A : IMyInterface {} // can pass into UtilityClass
public interface B : IMyInterface{}
public class C : B {} // can pass into UtilityClass
public class D {} // can Not pass into UtilityClass

public class UtilityClass<T is IMyInterface>
{
// some utility function
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for a generic constraint. These are expressed in C# by using the `where` keyword after the class name.

```
public class UtilityClass<T> where T:IMyInterface
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class UtilityClass<T> where T: IMyInterface
{
// some utility function
}
```

They are called constraints, you can read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use the where clause:

```
public interface IMyInterface 
{}


public class UtilityClass<T> where T : IMyInterface
{
// some utility function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add restrictions to generic classes like so:

```
public class UtilityClass<T> where T : IMyInterface
{
// some utility function
}
```